# Setting focus on dropdown autocomplete option by arrow keys in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I was unable to achieve my goal of picking options in an angular autocomplete dropdown that I created using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MN-pi2GMw4). This is what the component looks like now:
[Dropdown with focus on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMDve.png)

The dropdown options can be picked by clicking on them and they end up on the input field. I would also like to be able to pick the options by arrow keys, but am unable to do it. My code looks like this:

**autocomplete-select.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group row" clickOutside (clickOutside)="closeAllocationDropDown()" class="pos-rel">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="allocation" placeholder="Zadajte časový záznam" formControlName="allocation" (click)="toggleAllocationDropDown()" autofocus="autofocus">
  <div *ngIf="showAllocationDropdown" class="dropdown" > 
    <div>
      <div (click)="selectAllocation(a.name)" class="allocation" *ngFor="let a of allocations | filterAllocation: getAllocationValue()">
          {{a.name}}
      </div>
    </div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

**autocomplete-select.component.ts**

```
toggleAllocationDropDown() {
    this.showAllocationDropdown = !this.showAllocationDropdown;
  }

  closeAllocationDropDown() {
    this.showAllocationDropdown = false;
  }

  getAllocationValue() {
    return this.selectForm.value.allocation;
  }

  selectAllocation(value: string) {
    this.selectForm.controls['allocation'].setValue(value);
    this.showAllocationDropdown = false;   
  }
```

**autocomplete-select.component.scss**

```
.dropdown {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    //max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    max-height:300px;
    background:white;
    overflow-y:auto;
}   

.pos-rel {
    position: relative;
}

.allocation{
    padding:10py;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    color:black;
    background-color:$color-soft-grey;
}

.allocation:hover{
    background-color:$color-text;
}

input {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I imagine I need to create a directive for setting the focus on the dropdown option, but I'm not exactly sure how to research these options.

Comment: [The documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#keyboard-interaction) indicates that keyboard events are handled by default. Isn't that your issue ?

Comment: I'm not using the dropdown from angular material though.I'm using a customly-made one as described by the tutorial, because I need to be able to style the input the same as the other inputs in the application

Comment: My bad, jumped to conclusions ! would it be possible to get a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyup events to select what you want :

```
(keyup.arrowup)="selectPrevious()"
(keyup.arrowdown)="selectNext()"
```